# how to allocate memory for a struct inside a linked list in c?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I wrote these structures and function to add a link to a linked list but I get segmentation fault. Why is that happening?

```
typedef struct primaries_date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int time;
} primaries_date;

typedef struct usa_primaries {
    primaries_date *date;
    char *state;
    int open;
    struct usa_primaries *next;
} usa_primaries;

usa_primaries *head = NULL;

void insert(int day, int month, int time, char *state, int open){
    usa_primaries *temp, *entry = (usa_primaries     *)malloc(sizeof(usa_primaries));
    entry->date = (primaries_date *)malloc(sizeof(primaries_date));
    if(entry == NULL || entry->date==NULL){
        printf("error couldnt allocate memory");
        return;
    }
    entry->date->day = day;
    entry->date->month = month;
    entry->date->time = time;
    entry->state = state;
    entry->open = open; 

    if(head ==NULL){
        head = entry;
    } else {
        temp = head;
        while(temp!=NULL)
            temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = entry;
    }
    entry->next = NULL;
}
```

I believe that the problem is with the memory allocation of the date structure but not sure.

Comment: Please do not cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: He is not, but defining his temp pointer there feels bad to me. Mixing initialized variable declaration with non-initialized variable declaration is already iffy, but declaring a variable at function entrance when it is only in a very small subscope is worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating on `temp` until it is equal to `NULL`, then you are dereferencing it. Your condition for your while loop should be `temp->next != NULL`.

Comment: also, don't write `if(entry == NULL || entry->date==NULL)`                                      if one is malloced sucsessfully so he will not get the free and you will not be able to free him ever again. don'y mess with non-free memory.

Comment: @רועי אבידן, why shouldn't he write that? If the first condition is met, the 2nd will not be evaluated; if the first fails, it is safe to evaluate to 2nd. Anything wrong with that? His bug is that the assignment `entry->date=` can fail if the first `malloc` failed.

Comment: thanks a lot ! the condition of ending the loop really was the problem

Comment: because if the first malloc will work and the second will fail how he will know to free the first?